# Best reference doc for Kafka API

Tags: apache-kafka

I'd like to create a Kafka client in JavaScript or extend an existing implementation (eg https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs). I know that Kafka itself is language agnostic, however I have been unable to locate complete, language agnostic documentation for Kafka's APIs. As an example, http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#api simply links to the JavaDocs. Something like https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Transactional+Messaging+in+Kafka, describing the transactional API, is a bit closer to what I'm looking for.

Where might I find such a document that would enable me to begin working on a client implementation? Thanks.

EDIT:

Perhaps https://kafka.apache.org/protocol contains the spec?

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka? I _believe_ (but haven't used it) this is generally the most functional and performant NodeJS client for Kafka. It's built around the [`librdkafka`](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) library.

Comment: Also depending on what you're building there's the [REST Proxy](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest) if you just want to use HTTP for sending and receiving messages from Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Kafka project itself is JVM based, hence JavaDoc.

The protocol link itself defines the TCP message layout you would send, but otherwise, each client that implements that protocol must document itself.

See existing clients here - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients